# How to use a custom deserializer to deserialize classes with a prefined desserializer(java.util.UUID)

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, jackson, uuid, jackson-databind

In a class of my program, there is an `id` field of type `java.util.UUID`. When the field is mapped and stored in the Mongodb, it becomes `LUUID()`(legacy UUID, sub-type 0x03).

I would like to register a custom serializer and deserializer to the `ObjectMapper` to convert it to `UUID`(sub-type 0x04) object when stored in DB, while staying `java.util.UUID` in the main program.

**My Attempt:**

I managed to use a custom serializer to write the `UUID` object to Mongodb, but I cannot have to map back to the `java.util.UUID` when deserialize

I have two helper functions that can transform from and to java.util.UUID to org.bson.types.Binary(which be convert to UUID object when stored in mongodb

```
fun fromStandardBinaryUUID(binary: Binary): UUID 
fun toStandardBinaryUUID(uuid: UUID): Binary
```

**Serializer.kt**

```
class UUIDSerializer(t: Class<UUID>): StdSerializer<UUID>(t){
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun serialize(uuid: UUID, jsonGenerator: JsonGenerator,
                           serializerProvider: SerializerProvider?) {
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(toStandardBinaryUUID(uuid))
    }
}
```

**Deserializer.kt**

```
class UUIDDeserializer(t: Class<*>): StdDeserializer<UUID>(t) {
    constructor() : this(UUID::class.java)

    @Throws(IOException::class, JsonProcessingException::class)
    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, deserializer: DeserializationContext?): UUID {
        val binary = parser.readValueAs(Binary::class.java)
        val uuid = fromStandardBinaryUUID(binary);

        return uuid;  // garbage value, not that actual id.
    }
}
```

**Code for registration**

```
            val uuidSerializer = UUIDSerializer(UUID::class.java)
            val uuidDeserializer = UUIDDeserializer(UUID::class.java)
            val module = SimpleModule("UUIDSerializer");
            module.addDeserializer(UUID::class.java, uuidDeserializer).addSerializer(UUID::class.java, uuidSerializer);
            KMongoConfiguration.registerBsonModule(module)
```

**Implemntation of fromStandardBinaryUUID && toStandardBinaryUUID**

```
    fun fromStandardBinaryUUID(binary: Binary): UUID {
        var msb: Long = 0
        var lsb: Long = 0
        val uuidBytes = binary.data
        for (i in 8..15) {
            lsb = lsb shl 8
            lsb = lsb or uuidBytes[i].toLong() and 0xFFL
        }
        for (i in 0..7) {
            msb = msb shl 8
            msb = msb or uuidBytes[i].toLong() and 0xFFL
        }
        return UUID(msb, lsb)
    }

    fun toStandardBinaryUUID(uuid: UUID): Binary {
        var msb = uuid.mostSignificantBits
        var lsb = uuid.leastSignificantBits
        val uuidBytes = ByteArray(16)
        for (i in 15 downTo 8) {
            uuidBytes[i] = (lsb and 0xFFL).toByte()
            lsb = lsb shr 8
        }
        for (i in 7 downTo 0) {
            uuidBytes[i] = (msb and 0xFFL).toByte()
            msb = msb shr 8
        }
        return Binary(0x04.toByte(), uuidBytes)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A unit test with a serialization and then a deserialization is available here: https://github.com/Litote/kmongo/commit/97afc3ee309dd2b25e46ba95bb9678fb10006c63

Comment: thanks for your reply. I realize that we code does the same thing except that you are serializing the `UUID` into `ByteArray`, where as I serialize it into to`org.bson.types.Binary`. That's where the error is introduced. p.s. `Binary` object will be recognizes as `UUID` object in MongoDb while ByteArray is recognized as `Binary` object in Mongodb.

Comment: I have included the two conversion function if you would like to give it a try.

Comment: I am guessing that jackson has a serializer that convert a `Binary` object into `{"type":4,"data":"yTKE2jOVQkyGwyUiIE9Gvg=="}` this, but doesn't have a deserializer that maps it back to a `Binary` object